Get Development \ Releases fields using API in Jira
We are using Jira cloud and want to export a few items including all their data.
The only values we are failing to get are the Development links, which are links to a GitHub repository. (PR, Commit, etc.)
Is there a way to export this kind of data using API? Or else?
I've tried using the api, version 2.0 and 3.0 which didn't return an atcual link to GitHub.

Calling https://NAME.atlassian.net/rest/dev-status/latest/issue/detail?issueId=10195&applicationType=GitHub&dataType=branch returns:
{
  "errors": [],
  "detail": [
    {
      "branches": [
        {
          "name": "[REMOVED]-branch-SFF-27",
          "url": "https://github.com/[REMOVED]/1st_repository/tree/[REMOVED]-branch-SFF-27",
          "createPullRequestUrl": "https://github.com/[REMOVED]/1st_repository/pull/new/[REMOVED]-branch-SFF-27",
          "repository": {
            "name": "[REMOVED]/1st_repository",
            "url": "https://github.com/[REMOVED]/1st_repository",
            "branches": []
          },
          "lastCommit": {
            "id": "85663xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "displayId": "85663f",
            "authorTimestamp": "2019-10-31T16:53:18.000+0000",
            "url": "https://github.com/[REMOVED]/1st_repository/commit/85663fxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "author": {
              "name": "[REMOVED]"
            },
            "fileCount": 0,
            "merge": false,
            "message": "Create SFF-27 again",
            "files": []
          }
        }
      ],
      "pullRequests": [],
      "repositories": [],
      "_instance": {
        "name": "GitHub",
        "baseUrl": "https://github.com",
        "type": "GitHub",
        "id": "com.github.integration.production",
        "typeName": "GitHub",
        "singleInstance": true
      }
    }
  ]
}

Same can be done for Repository & pullrequest
